# How to make work single table inheritance and attr_accessible?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, single-table-inheritance

In a rails application, I have a base model like this :

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :name
end
```

And an inheritance from this model, like this :

```
class Provider < User
  belongs_to :user

  attr_accessible :business_name, :contact_name, :business_phone_number,
    :business_email, :website, :user_id
end
```

When I do :

```
Provider.new.user_id
```

It say `NoMethodError: undefined method 'user_id' for #<Provider:0x007f63ec8b3790>`.

When I just do `Provider.new` I have this:

```
#<Provider id: nil, name: nil, email: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, type: "Provider">
```

This is a part of my schema.rb :

```
  create_table "providers", :force => true do |t|
    t.string  "business_name",         :null => false
    t.string  "contact_name",          :null => false
    t.string  "business_phone_number", :null => false
    t.string  "business_email",        :null => false
    t.string  "website"
    t.integer "user_id"
  end

  create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "email"
    t.datetime "created_at",                             :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                             :null => false
  end
```

As you can see, the attributes accessibles for Provider are not accessible. Do you have a solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in the answer to [Single Table Inheritance to refer to a child class with its own fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5883061/single-table-inheritance-to-refer-to-a-child-class-with-its-own-fields), `ActiveRecord`'s implementation of Single Table Inheritance does not involve additional tables.  All subclasses share the same table and rely on a `type` field to identify subclasses. That explains why your `Provider` instances only contain the fields available in your `users` table, including the `type` field that Rails adds for the subclassing support. Your `providers` table is unused.

Answer (score 0):

The same table is used at the database level. STI is achieved by adding a new column to the existing table. The new column usually named 'type' is used to hold the information whether it is a 'Provider' or 'User'

Here is how the the model queries translate to a sql query

When the User model is queried, as per your example, it searches 'users' table and includes all available type values in the condition

```
> User.first
SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users`  WHERE `users`.`type` IN ('User', 'Provider')  ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
```

When the Provider model is queried, type is set as 'Provider' in the condition and so the results get filtered. The underlying database table remains the same ie 'users'

```
 > Provider.first
SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users`  WHERE `users`.`type` IN ('Provider')  ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
```