# NoMethodError in controller #new action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

The solution might be obvious but I have looked at a lot of posts on Stackoverflow and couldn't solve this error.

```
app/views/sellers/_form.html.erb where line #16 raised:
undefined method `name' for #<Seller:0x007fbedb5f3ce0>

    Extracted source (around line #16):   

 <div class="field">
   <%= f.label :name %><br>
   <%= f.text_field :name %>
 </div>
```

**beginning of _form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(@seller) do |f| %>
  <% if @seller.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@seller.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this seller from being saved:</h2>
      <ul>
        <% @seller.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
          <li><%= msg %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
```

**sellers_controller** (edit : here is the controller asked below)

```
class SellersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @seller = Seller.new
  end
end
```

**schema.rb**

```
create_table "sellers", force: true do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.string   "person_type"
  t.string   "rep_first_name"
  t.string   "rep_last_name"
  t.date     "rep_birthday"
  t.string   "rep_nationality"
  t.string   "rep_country_of_residence"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
  t.integer  "mp_id"
  t.integer  "mp_walletid"
end
```

**seller.rb**

```
class Seller < User
  has_many :resas
  has_many :buyers, :through => :resas
  validates :name, :person_type, :rep_first_name, :rep_last_name, :rep_birthday, :rep_nationality, :rep_country_of_residence, presence: true
  validates :name, length: { maximum: 255 }
  validates :rep_first_name, :rep_last_name, length: { maximum: 100 }
  validates :rep_nationality, :rep_country_of_residence, length: { is: 2 }
  def seller?
    self.is_a?(Seller)
  end
end
```

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :seller, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :seller
  has_one :buyer, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :buyer
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  def type
    self.type
  end
end
```

Comment: if the error is in your controller, please post your controller.

Comment: How does your `seller` model look? what are the attributes?

Comment: Try restarting rails server

Comment: I restarted it twice but there is still the error. Can this be related to the inheritance of Seller from User model ?

Answer (score 4):

The error :

`undefined method 'name' for #<Seller:0x007fbedb5f3ce0>`

will occur when you don't have attribute `name` defined for `Seller` model. 
To resolve this issue, either add `name` as a field to `sellers` table or make it as a virtual attribute in `Seller` model depending upon your requirement.

**UPDATE**

Looks like you are trying to implement Single Table Inheritance(STI).

If that is the case, then you should be having just a **single table i.e., users** with a field named `type` which is used for identification of the child like `Seller` in your case.

I would highly recommend reading @tadman's answer [Single Table Inheritance to refer to a child class with its own fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5883061/single-table-inheritance-to-refer-to-a-child-class-with-its-own-fields). It will definitely help you to setup proper STI.

Comment: Share the `schema.rb` file in the question, so we can verify that  `name` field does exist in `sellers` table.

Comment: That's strange. Then, I doubt that there is some problem in the model. Can you share the model `Seller` in the question.

Comment: Thanks. Could you also share the User model as Seller inherits it.

Comment: Just shared. An other thought that could help, sooner, Devise was added to Seller, but I removed it (cleanly I thought, through down-migration and rails devise destroy). Then, I added Devise to User.

Comment: Thank you. I did implement STI with a field `type`in User. I've read the page you recommend but I don't understand in what way this helps me here. This seem very complex. User has `email`, `password` required fields, but Seller has required fields which are different from Buyer's required fields (Buyer also inherits from User). 
My implementation is based on @mohamagdy's answer [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9472852/devise-and-multiple-user-models)

Comment: If you notice in the linked answer, tadman has shown how STI should be implemented and also how the additional fields if required, should be added to a new model (refer admin_profiles and common_profiles example in his answer)